# Prevent a column to be dragged or resized

Tags: smartgwt

I have a column in a `ListGrid` and I want this column to be frozen. I don't want users to be able to drag the header and resize this column's width.

I tried

```
column.setCanDragResize(false)
```

but had no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First plz post code snippet or at least smart GWT version.
Second, that method works fine in this case:

```
    ListGrid list = new ListGrid();
    list.setWidth(500);
    list.setHeight(300);

    ListGridField listField = new ListGridField("first");
    listField.setCanDragResize(false);

    list.setFields(listField);
    list.draw();
```

If u want all fields to be disabled then you can use:

```
    ListGrid list = new ListGrid();
    list.setCanResizeFields(false);
    list.setWidth(500);
    list.setHeight(300);

    ListGridField listField = new ListGridField("first");

    ListGridField listField2 = new ListGridField("second");

    ListGridField listField3 = new ListGridField("third");


    list.setFields(listField,listField2,listField3);
    list.draw();
```

EDIT: you can also set `list.setCanReorderFields(false);` if u dont want to reorder fields

Regards, Jakov A.